# How Can I Change the Font Size in Printing?

Tags: c#, winforms, printing

How can I change the font size of my printings? This is the code I'm using.

```
private void PrintDocumentOnPrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
     e.Graphics.DrawString(
        this.textBox5.Text + " " + this.textBox6.Text + " - " + this.textBox8.Text, 
        this.textBox5.Font, Brushes.Black, 10, 25);            
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     MessageBox.Show("Bienvenido, Toma tú Gafete!");    
     PrintDocument printDocument = new PrintDocument();
     printDocument.PrintPage += PrintDocumentOnPrintPage;
     printDocument.Print();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make [a new `Font` object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141985.aspx) with the same family and style as the old font, but a different size; then pass that font to `DrawString` instead of the old one.

```
float size = 14; // for example
var oldFont = textBox5.Font;
var newFont = new Font(oldFont.FontFamily, size, oldFont.FontStyle);

e.Graphics.DrawString(
    this.textBox5.Text + " " + this.textBox6.Text + " - " + this.textBox8.Text, 
    newFont, Brushes.Black, 10, 25);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a new Font like this:

```
Font myFont = new Font(FontName, FontSize);
```

Look here for the documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.drawing.font%28v=vs.110%29.aspx